# Stop compiling if a called function is not supported under OS

Tags: c, cross-platform, preprocessor

I am creating a C library which is supposed to be cross-platform.

For the time being, I have a function:

```
void example() {
#ifdef __linux__
    // do stuff
#else
    // Not implemented
#endif
}
```

As you can see above, I have written some code for linux, but other OSes are not supported (as of now at least).

Is there a way to stop compilation ONLY if the function is called?

In other words, what I want to do is to not allow someone to build a project under an unsupported OS ONLY IF this (or another unimplemented function) is called. BUT i want to still be able to build the library for other Operating Systems IF that function is never used.

I can probably just use this:

```
#ifdef __linux__
void example() {
}
#endif
```

But I want to show a more descriptive message using pragma/error explaining that this function is not supported. (To avoid confusion on why it doesn't build)

Comment: Do you know of `#error Descriptive message`? You make it conditional (or nothing would compile).

Comment: @WeatherVane yes but ```#error``` will stop compilation even if this function is NOT called in the code. I don't want that. I only want to stop compilation ONLY if the function is supposed to be used.

Comment: If the function isn't supported you can make a placeholder function instead. Or if you omit the function conditionally, then the compilation will fail when it sees the unsuppported call.

Comment: But then how would I stop compilation? That would be disabling something without notifying. It's important functionality and it's pointless for some projects to build without it

Comment: In your second example, the compiler already tells you of the error when it tries to compile `example();`. If the function isn't there then you can't compile a call to it. I don't understand your problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane But in this case it says the function doesn't exist. My case should show it is not supported. I feel like it would be better that way.

Comment: If you have `#define example Unsupported_function_example` the compiler will then warn `'Unsupported_function_example' undefined` and the linker will fail.

Comment: What compiler(s) are you using?  You need to get them to emit an *error* if you encounter any function without a prototype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the real function is `void example (void)` but not present in the current build, you ought to get linker errors.

If that's still not good enough and you must have compiler errors, then consider "mocking" the function with a macro generating a compiler error as soon as it is used, but only then:

```c
#ifdef __linux__
    // example() is present
#else
    #define example() do { _Static_assert(0, "example() not supported"); } while(0)
#endif
```

Comment: But doesn't `_Static_assert` require Linux?

Comment: @WeatherVane Eh? It's a standard C keyword since 2011. As per C23 you can also do `static_assert` without including assert.h.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be supported by MS VC, which has `_STATIC_ASSERT(booleanExpression);` (one argument).

Comment: @WeatherVane https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/static-assert-c?view=msvc-170

Comment: @WeatherVane You need to use a C compiler, that some non-conforming non-C from 1989. Sic: Visual Studio 2022 or later in C mode is a compiler from 1989.

Comment: @user18812922 despite what the page says, my 2022 MS VC supports `static_assert()` but not `_Static_assert()`.

Comment: @Lundin That works but I have a question, why use do-while loop instead of simply _Static_assert()?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah? Try `_Static_assert(__STDC__==0, "If this pops up as a compiler message, your compiler is not hopelessly broken.");` Pure standard C.

Comment: @user18812922 `_Static_assert` works like a declaration so `if(cond) example();` won't work without the do-while(0) trick.

Comment: @Lundin Weird, I just removed the do-while and it works. (using GCC under linux)

Comment: @user18812922 It depends on what the calling code looks like. Anyway, the do-while(0) won't do any harm at least. There's situations when you don't want to use the trick, for example when writing end applications with strict coding standards. [What is do { } while(0) in macros and should we use it?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/279576)